# overlay texture in after effects

Tags: overlay, after-effects

probably this is a dumb question, but i can't figure it out

Is there a way to overlay a texture on certain objects, using AE ?

Example. I have a 3DS render of a door in brown and would like to use another texture of that door, without rendering the same scene 2 times (second time would be with the alternative texture)

Thanks for any help on this

Answer (score 0):

Make your layer "add" or "Overlay".

https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/865800